# Chrome App add click events on button/input inside the Webview

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, webview, google-chrome-app

I have made this chrome app which uses a webview to load the content from a certain link. My problem is I cannot figure out how to add click or other events to elements inside, for example a button.
I need to use the webview, so building the content inside the extension is not an option.
I also need to communicate/change with the webview elements, because I need to get data from a USB device and populate some inputs in the webview.

I have either tried everything I have found with no luck or I did it badly.

Thx!

This is my index.html from the package

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<webview id="webview" partition="persist:googlepluswidgets" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="full trim"  src="http://urlOfApplication.com" ></webview>

<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="port.js"></script>
<script src="printer.js"></script>
</body>
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Tezaur - LOCAL",
  "version": "1.0.4",  
  "description": "Tezaur Amanet App",
  "permissions": ["webview", "serial","usb","videoCapture","fullscreen", "storage"],
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "gold-16.png",
    "128": "gold-128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
      // Center window on screen.
  var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
  var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;

    chrome.app.window.create('popup.html', {
        // 'id': 'amanet-app',
        'state' : 'maximized',
        'resizable' : true,
        'alwaysOnTop' : false,
        state: 'maximized'
    },
    function(win) {
        win.maximize();
        // win.clearAttention();
        // win.restore();
    }
    );

});

chrome.app.window.onClosed.addListener(function() {
  // Do some simple clean-up tasks.
  $.ajax({url:"http://tezaur-local/auth/logout", async:false});
  //var expires = new Date();
//  expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    //document.cookie = 'laravel_session=;path=/;expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
});

//chrome.app.window.canSetVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use [webview.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-executeScript)  to run a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) inside the `webview`, because it would have access to the `webview`'s DOM.

For example:

```
document.querySelector('webview').executeScript({
  code: 'document.getElementById("button-id").onclick = function() { /* click handler */ }',
  function(results) { if (results && results.length) { /* successful script injection */ }
});
```